# CS0246 error notification on VS, but no error is shown in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I need to build a custom inspector for my project, so after some research I manage to implement a simple class for testing. But a strange behaviour is bugging me, my custom inspector class is showing the CS0246 error when I use any of my classes, while in Unity, no error is shown. The project runs normally and my script does modifies the inspector as expected, but I would like to solve this situation and remove this error notification from VS. Other scripts doesn't show any errors, this situation is happening just with this custom inspector script.

This is an image showing what I described above:

[image]

EDIT - This is my ChampionshipInternalCreator class as resquested:

[image]

EDIT 2 - This is the alt+enter suggestions:

[image]

"ChampionshipInternalCreatorCustomInspector" script is at: Assets\Scripts\Internal data management\Data creation and testing\Editor

"ChampionshipInternalCreator" script is at:
Assets\Scripts\Internal data management\Data creation and testing\Championship creation

As far as I know, it should be working normally as documentation states:

[image]

I also notice that this script doesn't make VS point errors the way a normal script does. For example, if I produce an error, VS doesn't point the error but Unity does.

Comment: Are you sure, **ChampionshipInternalCreator** script has **public** accessor? If ChampionshipInternalCreator script has a namespace, you should specify and access it with namespace.

Comment: As Selectra points, please attach your ChampionshipInternalCreator script please

Comment: Just edited the question @SeLeCtRa. Not sure if editions send notifications...

Comment: Just edited the question @Lotan. Not sure if editions send notifications...

Comment: @GabrielMinosso if you click alt+enter while cursor is blinking on your error, which corrections suggest VS? (and seems like no, editions do not send notifications). Also, is your Editor script inside an Editor folder?

Comment: @Lotan That can cause only in builds. If that's the only problem, it should work seamlessly in editor.

Comment: @GabrielMinosso, Just in case try to reimport all scripts in your project and use Visual Studio ReBuild All function. See if that's fix the problem. If that's not a fix for you problem, can you show us folder hierarchy for your scripts? Where **ChampionshipInternalCreator ** script and **ChampionshipCustomInspector** located?

Comment: @SeLeCtRa Just added the script's directories as requested. Not sure how to reimport all scripts or use this "ReBuild All" command.

Comment: Just right click Scripts folder in Unity Editor and click **ReImport**. Make sure there are only scripts in folder. If there are any large assets it will take so long. For **Rebuild**, In Visual Studio, there is Build Tab and select Rebuild All.

Comment: And I want to ask a little thing, is there any active (Not commented out) preprocessor like (UNITY_ANDROID, UNITY_EDITOR) in your script. That can cause this type of problem. Also make sure in solution explorer in Visual Studio, Editor Assembly has reference to Main Assembly. [Assembly Sample](https://ibb.co/6J2cKnY)

Comment: @Lotan Directories added, forgot to mention you as editions seemingly doesn't send notifications...

Comment: @SeLeCtRa Scripts reimported and project rebuilded, but through the "Rebuild solution" button, as my build tab doesn't have a "Rebuild all" button. Just checked both scripts and there isn't any active preprocessors and my [solution explorer](https://ibb.co/zZQP4dq) seems like yours I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228914/discussion-between-gabriel-minosso-and-selectra).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SeLeCtRa help through chat, the problem were solved.

For some reason the reference to the **Assembly-CSharp** were lost, which makes an small alert icon appear in the solution explorer, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qAdA.jpg).

Firstly, I had to delete the problematic **Assembly-CSharp** reference, then, with **Analyzer** option selected, navigate to the **Project** tab, then click on **Add reference**. This will open the **Reference Manager** window, where you should select the **Projects** tab and mark the **Assembly-CSharp**.

In my case though, this option wasn't available, so I had to click the **Browse** button and navigate to my project folder, there, if you search for "Assembly-CSharp", 2 files with that name will be returned. The correct one is at **YourProjectFolder\obj\Debug** directory. After mark this file, the problem is solved.